# How correctly to set two navigation drawer of Vuetify framework?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, vue-props

In my `Vue.JS` application, I am trying to use two `v-navigation-drawer` of `Vuetify` framework. For some reason, my next code raises an error. In my case, each of the sidebars is in a separate component. How to fix such error?

**Error:**

> vue.esm.js?efeb:628 [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since
>   the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component
>   re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the
>   prop's value. Prop being mutated: "open"

**BaseLayout.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-app-bar app>
      <v-btn
        icon
        @click.stop="openLeftNavigationDrawer=!openLeftNavigationDrawer">
        <v-icon>mdi-map-clock-outline</v-icon>
      </v-btn>

      <v-spacer></v-spacer>

      <v-btn
        icon
        @click.stop="openRightNavigationDrawer=!openRightNavigationDrawer">
        <v-icon>mdi-filter</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-app-bar>

    <left-navigation-drawer
      :open="openLeftNavigationDrawer">
    </left-navigation-drawer>

    <right-navigation-drawer
      :open="openRightNavigationDrawer">
    </right-navigation-drawer>

    <v-content style="padding:unset!important;">
      <slot></slot>
    </v-content>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import LeftNavigationDrawer from '../elements/LeftNavigationDrawer'
import RightNavigationDrawer from '../elements/RightNavigationDrawer'

export default {
  name: 'BaseLayout',
  components: {
    LeftNavigationDrawer,
    RightNavigationDrawer
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      openLeftNavigationDrawer: false,
      openRightNavigationDrawer: false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**LeftNavigationDrawer.vue:**

```
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer
    v-model="open"
    absolute
    left>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'LeftNavigationDrawer',
  props: {
    open: false
  }
}
</script>
```

**RightNavigationDrawer.vue:**

```
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer
    v-model="open"
    absolute
    right>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'RightNavigationDrawer',
  props: {
    open: false
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you `LeftNavigationDrawer` and `RightNavigationDrawer` components, when you write `v-model="open"`, it allows the `v-navigation-drawer` component to change the value of `open`.

But, in VueJS, a component is not allowed to change the value of it's props. Only the parent can do that. Since, `open` is a prop and `v-navigation-bar` is trying to change it, you see the error `Avoid mutating a prop...`.

In order to fix it, you can define a `data` in your components that is sent to `v-navigation-drawer`. Something like this:

```
// RightNavigationDrawer.vue/LeftNavigationDrawer
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer
    v-model="drawerOpen"
    @input="onInput"
    absolute
    right>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'RightNavigationDrawer',
  props: {
    open: {
       type: Boolean,
       default: false
    }

  },
 data(){
   return {
      drawerOpen: this.open
   }
 },
 watch:{
   open(newVal){
      this.drawerOpen = newVal
   }
 },
 methods:{
   onInput(isOpen){
      this.$emit('drawerOpened', isOpen)
   }
 }
}
</script>
```

- The data `drawerOpen` stores whether Vuetify's `v-navigation-drawer` is opened or not.
- The watch over `open` allows you to change the drawer state whenever `open` prop changes (Parent to Child communication)
- The `@input` handler allows you to send new drawer state to the parent component (Child to Parent communication)

Once you have made changes to the Left and Right Navigation Drawer components, your `BaseLayout.vue` will need to listen for the `drawerOpened` event.

```
// BaseLayout.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <v-app-bar app>
      <v-btn
        icon
        @click.stop="openLeftNavigationDrawer=!openLeftNavigationDrawer">
        <v-icon>mdi-map-clock-outline</v-icon>
      </v-btn>

      <v-spacer></v-spacer>

      <v-btn
        icon
        @click.stop="openRightNavigationDrawer=!openRightNavigationDrawer">
        <v-icon>mdi-filter</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-app-bar>

    <left-navigation-drawer
      :open="openLeftNavigationDrawer"
      @drawer-opened="handleDrawerChange("left", $event)"   // Add these event handlers
    >
    </left-navigation-drawer>

    <right-navigation-drawer
      :open="openRightNavigationDrawer"
      @drawer-opened="handleDrawerChange("right", $event)"
    >
    </right-navigation-drawer>

    <v-content style="padding:unset!important;">
      <slot></slot>
    </v-content>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import LeftNavigationDrawer from '../elements/LeftNavigationDrawer'
import RightNavigationDrawer from '../elements/RightNavigationDrawer'

export default {
  name: 'BaseLayout',
  components: {
    LeftNavigationDrawer,
    RightNavigationDrawer
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      openLeftNavigationDrawer: false,
      openRightNavigationDrawer: false
    }
  },
  methods:{
    handleDrawerChange(type, isOpen){
       if(type === "left"){
          this.openLeftNavigationDrawer = isOpen
       }else{
          this.openRightNavigationDrawer = isOpen
       }
    }

  }
}
</script>
```

- In your HTML, you listen for `drawer-opened` event.
- In the event handler, you pass 2 params: one is whether the drawer is left or right. The other param is the value received from the component.
- Based on whether the drawer is left or right, you change the value of appropriate data in `BaseLayout.vue`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I notice the strange behavior in small (`600px > < 960px`) screen devices. Let's say I open the right navigation drawer, then I click the left button which needs to open the left navigation drawer. In that case, the right navigation drawer closed and the left navigation drawer opened. In that case, the value of `openRightNavigationDrawer` variable didn't change. I need to change that value in small screen devices. Do you have any ideas about this behavior?

Comment: I don't know why but `handleDrawerChange` method is never called.

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek I am unable to reproduce your scenario.
Here's a codesanbox with your code: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-4f24x. In this `handleDrawerChange` is being called.
Can you fork this and try to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Also, please consider accepting my answer by clicking the `tick` icon, so that it helps other developers in the community

Comment: Also, note that you don't need 2 drawers. You can just create one drawer(NavigationDrawer) and set the `right` prop as true for the right navigation drawer.
Even better would be to use the `v-navigation-drawer` directly in `BaseLayout.vue` and have no extra drawer component.